# Tinymce change elements

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I have multiple text areas, where I add the TinyMce toolbar:

```
<div id='ques_1'>
<input type='button' onclick='loadTinyMce(1)' value='Edit'>
</div>
<div id='ques_2'>
<input type='button' onclick='loadTinyMce(2)' value='Edit'>
</div>
<div id='ques_3'>
<input type='button' onclick='loadTinyMce(3)' value='Edit'>
</div>
<div id='ques_4'>
<input type='button' onclick='loadTinyMce(4)' value='Edit'>
</div>
```

JavaScript function

```
function loadTinyMce(index)
{

   var elem= 'ques_'+index;

   tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "exact",
        elements : elem,

        theme : "advanced",
        width : "100%",
        plugins : "autoresize,paste,table,inlinepopups",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 :"",
   }
  );

}
```

I am dynamically building the elements for tiny mce init , but it does not work , so is there a way to change the elements attribute of tinymce to load for the clicked div.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hanging comma at the end of your object declaration:

`theme_advanced_buttons3 :"",}`

`theme_advanced_buttons3 :""}`